# Wrap list around in Python

Tags: python

I'm making a cipher where a text input is given and the output is the input but shifted along 2 in the alphabet for example "hi" is turned into "jk". I'm having problems wrapping the list around so that "y" can turn into "b" and so on.
Plaintext is a set input.
Key is 2

```
charset=["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"] # characters to be encrypted

def caesar_encrypt(plaintext,key):

    plaintext = plaintext.upper() # convert plaintext to upper case
    ciphertext = "" # initialise ciphertext as empty string

    for ch in plaintext:
        if ch == " ":
            pass
        else:
            index = charset.index(ch)
            newIndex = index + key
            shiftedCharacter = charset[newIndex]
            ciphertext += shiftedCharacter
            print(ciphertext)
    return ciphertext
```

Comment: try `newIndex = (index + key) % len(charset)` (meet _integer modulo_)

Comment: The indentation in this is just plain messed up which can cause problems.

Comment: On another note, `charset = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"` words just as well and is a lot more compact. You could even do `import string` and then use `string.ascii_uppercase`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change:

```
newIndex = index + key
```

To:

```
newIndex = (index + key) % len(charset)
```

This way, the values will wraparound gracefully

[Modulo (`%`) documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)

Answer (score 0):

To shift, you can try this:

```
import string

converter = {string.ascii_uppercase[i]:string.ascii_uppercase[i+2] for i in range(24)}
```

Comment: As far as I can see this won't wrap around for `z`. You need modulo, which has been covered by other answers.